# Setting up a Spring 3 MVC project with JPA on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, spring-mvc

I'm new to the whole Spring and JPA world, and I'm trying to set up a project so I can work on a small project I thought for learning purposes. I find this whole setting up very frustrating because of all the configuration it requires.

What I want to do is setup a Spring 3 MVC project and a have the entities in a separate JPA project (with Hibernate as the vendor), but I couldn't find any step-by-step tutorials or something like that to help me get started.

I'd really appreciate if you point me to a simple tutorial.

Comment: I feel your pain - I'm in the same boat, looking for a hello world walkthrough.  Like pulling teeth.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start [here](http://www.mkyong.com/), IMO he has the best beginners tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I finally got something to work (it's not easy coming from Visual Studio where everything is pre-canned, out of the box for you :) )

This URL did the trick for me: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html

However, I did have a couple of snags before it worked, even with that.  The first was that I didn't have commons-logging.jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder, and the second was that I didn't have jstl.jar in the same.  For the first, I had to look in the spring release itself, and for the second, I had to look in the tomcat distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've seen this tutorial and got it to work as well, the trouble started when I tried accessing the database :/

Comment: Haven't gotten to that yet.  Goal for today was just to get Spring 3 setup.  We'll see 'bout the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The process is best explained in step-by-step form:

http://www.sandeepsachan.com/helloword-demo-spring-mvc-3-0-eclipse.html